# How to calculate percentage of GPA > 3.5 from two tables?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have two tables tblStudent and tblTranscript. I want to calculate the percentage of students who have a GPA > 3.5. I have created two queries that give the count of total students with a GPA and total students with a GPA > 3.5.

I don't know how to divide these two tables and multiple them by 100 to get the percentage of students who have a GPA > 3.5.

My queries are:

GPA > 3.5

```
SELECT COUNT (GPA) FROM (
SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, studentID from tblTranscript
GROUP BY studentID HAVING avg(Grade) > 3.5)
```

TotalCountWithGPA

```
SELECT COUNT (GPA) FROM (
SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, StudentID FROM tblTranscript
GROUP BY StudentID)
```

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT

(COUNT (GPA) 
/ 
(SELECT COUNT(GPA) FROM (SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, StudentID FROM tblTranscript GROUP BY StudentID)) * 100) as PercentageOfStudents

FROM (SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, studentID from tblTranscript GROUP BY studentID HAVING avg(Grade) > 3.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT 
(COUNT (studentID)/(SELECT COUNT(studentID) FROM tblTranscript)) as percentageOfStudents 
FROM (
        SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, studentID from tblTranscript
        GROUP BY studentID HAVING avg(Grade) > 3.5)
```

Hopefully it would work as you are expecting

Comment: **EDIT**: `(COUNT (studentID)/(SELECT COUNT(studentID) FROM tblTranscript) * 100)`

Comment: Hmm this looks okay but it's not quite right. It's not giving the answer I'm looking for. The total students who have a GPA is 500 and the students with a GPA > 3.5 is 14. So 14/500 = .0028 * 100 = 2.8% but this is yielding .09596%

Answer (score 1):

I understood your problem now. I could not edit my last answer because of page not found error. Anyway, I have edited my last answer and posted. Check if it works,

```
SELECT 
(COUNT(GPA)/(SELECT COUNT(GPA) FROM (SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, studentID from tblTranscript)) * 100) as percentageOfStudents 
FROM (
        SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, studentID from tblTranscript
        GROUP BY studentID HAVING avg(Grade) > 3.5)
```

Comment: It says "Your query does not include the specified expression 'studentID' as part of an aggregate function."

Comment: `(COUNT(GPA)/(SELECT COUNT(GPA) FROM (SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA from tblTranscript))  * 100) as percentageOfStudents`. Replace the first line with this

Comment: My two queries I posted in the quest give the numbers, but I don't know how to write an expression that takes those numbers and divides them and multiply that number by 100

Comment: That results with 1400

Comment: SELECT COUNT(GPA) FROM (SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA from tblTranscript)  this expression is resulting with the count of 1 which is not correct

Comment: Because it is taking the average grade of ALL the grades listed on the Transcript table instead of taking the average GPA for each student and since there is only one GPA for all the grades which is like 3.2 or something the count only returns 1

Comment: you want to divide the number with total students who have GPA and then multiply the output with 100 right?

Comment: I just got the answer by tweaking your expression, but for some reason I can't multiple it by 100 to get the percentage.

Comment: SELECT

COUNT (GPA) 
/ 
(SELECT COUNT(GPA) FROM (SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, StudentID FROM tblTranscript GROUP BY StudentID))

FROM (SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, studentID from tblTranscript GROUP BY studentID HAVING avg(Grade) > 3.5)

Comment: Got it: SELECT

(COUNT (GPA) 
/ 
(SELECT COUNT(GPA) FROM (SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, StudentID FROM tblTranscript GROUP BY StudentID)) * 100) as PercentageOfStudents

FROM (SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, studentID from tblTranscript GROUP BY studentID HAVING avg(Grade) > 3.5)

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL or Access ?

For MySQL you can use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(GPA > 3.5)/COUNT(GPA)*100 as HIGH_GPA_PERC
FROM(SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, StudentID
     FROM tblTranscript
     GROUP BY StudentID) t
```

Comment: The last is not for Access, it's T-SQL.

Comment: When I run the first one I keep getting the result of 100. But it should be 14/500 * 100 = 2.8%

Comment: @ChaCol Which RDBMS are you using ?? And unless the grades are below 4, the AVG(grade) will always be > then 3.5 . Are you sure that's the number you wanna use ?

Comment: @Gustav Actually it's ANSI syntax, should work for almost any DBMS, but you are right, Access uses `SWITCH` instead .

Comment: I'm using tables that my professor gave me. There are 500 grades in this table and they range from 2 - 4 (2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, or 4) and there are several grades in this table per one Student.. so a student may have 10-15 grades. So I'm taking the average student grade and trying to find all of those GPAs that are > 3.5

Comment: Sorry there are over 14,000 grades in the table but 500 students with a GPA

Comment: Are you using MySQL ? If you run `SELECT COUNT(GPA > 3.5) as first, COUNT(GPA) as total FROM (select avg(Grade)..........` What do you get ? @ChaCol